# Prevent duplicate variables of the objects added as Values in a dictionary c#

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, hash, duplicates

I have a `Dictionary<int,int>` in my `Individual` class.

```
 public class Individual
    {
       Dictionary<int,int> pattern = new Dictionary<int,int>();
    }
```

I want to add an `<int,Individual>` pair to my `population` dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int,Individual> population = new Dictionary<int, Individual>();
```

If and only if there is no other `Individual` in the dictionary with a similar `pattern` variable.

My current approach is to naively iterate over every `pattern` of every `Individual` already present in the `population`, but I believe this can be done faster using a different approach.

```
public bool same_dict(Dictionary<int, int> p1, Dictionary<int, int> p2)
//Meant to compare patterns
{
    if (p1.Count != p1.Count) return false;
    foreach (var feature in p1)
    {
        if (p2.ContainsKey(feature.Key))
        {
            if (feature.Value != p2[feature.Key]) return false;
        }
        else return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public bool matched is_duplicated(Individual ind, Dictionary<int, Individual> pop)
{
//Meant to compare Individuals
    foreach (var ind2 in pop)
    {
        if (same_dict(ind.pattern, ind2.Value.pattern))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I must use the `ints` as keys for the `population` dictionary because I use it to link the `Individual` objects with other parts of the program.
A `pattern` dictionary can contain any amount of key:value pairs, that's why I verify if their `.Count` property is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that i correctly understand your issue, but...

> If and only if there is no other Individual in the dictionary with a
> similar pattern variable

"Similar pattern variable" means, as I think, that two `Individual` has `Pattern` dictionary with same key(s) and value(s) in it (don't know, how much "patterns" it could store).

So I tried to use LINQ's `.Any()` extension method to check for any `Individual`'s `Pattern` dictionary in `population` dictionary has same key and value as added `Individual`. It sounds complicated, so here is code example (console):

```
public class Individual
{
    public Dictionary<int, int> Pattern { get; set; } = new Dictionary<int, int>();
}

static void Main()
{
    var population = new Dictionary<int, Individual>();
    var key = 0;

    for (; key < 5; key++) // Fill population with some Individuals
    {
        var individual = new Individual();
        individual.Pattern.Add(key + 1, key + 2);

        population.Add(key, individual);
    }

    // Print current population:
    Console.WriteLine("Population Dictionary:");
    foreach (var kvp in population)
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " +
                          string.Join(" | ", kvp.Value.Pattern.Select(pattern => pattern.Key + "," + pattern.Value)));

    // Creating new Individuals, which we will try to add to population
    var newIndividual1 = new Individual();
    newIndividual1.Pattern.Add(5, 6);
    var newIndividual2 = new Individual();
    newIndividual2.Pattern.Add(5, 5);
    var newIndividual3 = new Individual();
    newIndividual3.Pattern.Add(8, 9);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Adding new Individuals:");

    if (AddIndividual(population, key, newIndividual1))
        key++;

    if (AddIndividual(population, key, newIndividual2))
        key++;

    if (AddIndividual(population, key, newIndividual3))
        key++;

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static bool AddIndividual(Dictionary<int, Individual> population, int newKey, Individual newIndividual)
{
    // Compare each Individual in population with newIndividual
    if (!population.Any(p => newIndividual.Pattern.Keys.Any(k => p.Value.Pattern.ContainsKey(k)) &&
                             newIndividual.Pattern.Values.Any(v => p.Value.Pattern.ContainsValue(v))))
    {
        population.Add(newKey, newIndividual);
        Console.WriteLine("Individual with pattern " +
                          string.Join(" | ", newIndividual.Pattern.Select(pattern => pattern.Key + "," + pattern.Value)) +
                          " successfully added to Population Dictionary.");

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Individual with pattern " +
                          string.Join(" | ", newIndividual.Pattern.Select(pattern => pattern.Key + "," + pattern.Value)) +
                          " already exists in Population Dictionary.");

        return false;
    }
}
```

Output sample:

[image]

**EDIT.**

You can replace comparing keys and values by `.Any` method with `.SequenceEqual`:

```
if (!population.Any(p => p.Value.Pattern.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key).SequenceEqual(newIndividual.Pattern.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key))))
{
    population.Add(newKey, newIndividual);
}
```

Comment: You got the problem right. An individual is similar to another if their pattern dictionary has the same keys with the same values. Said dictionaries can contain any amount of key,value pairs. I sped up the process by first verifying if both dictionaries counts are equal. If they are, I then iterate over every key:value pair. Your solution works and is very similar to what I'm doing but using '.Any' instead of iterating manually. Does this mean that there is no faster way to find duplicates in a dictionary? I expected some sort of hashtable solution but I cannot think of it as it is.

Comment: You have performance issues with this? Why need faster?

Comment: You can also replace comparing keys and values by `.Any` with `.SequenceEqual`. Check edit for example.